# Replace text with an image on pageload jQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery

I have to replace some text in a tablecell (class="tableHeader") with an image in **jQuery 1.5.2** on page load, I have it working when I click on the table cell but I cannot make it work on page load

This code works fine onClick. What do I have to change to make it work on pageload:

```
$().ready(function () {

    $('.tableHeader').live( "click", function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "Computed") {
            $(this).html("<img src='/images/computed.jpeg'  width='40px'>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.live` line (for jquery 1.5.2 as specified in the question)

```
$('.tableHeader').live( "click", function() {
```

to

```
$('.tableHeader').each(function() {
```

then it will loop each tableHeader with `this` as the tableHeader, so no need to change anything inside the loop.

---

There are alternative ways to do this, eg using an overload of [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".tableHeader").html(function(i, existing_html) {
    if (existing_html == "Computed") {
        return "<img src='/images/computed.jpeg' width='40px'>";
    }    
});
```

Comment: Hi Freedomn-m, thanks for your help. Unfortunately both ways do not work in my case. I think it has to do on how the page is setup. If I inspect the sourcecode in the browserconsole I can see the elements with class tableHeader. If I inspect the Sourcecode of the page  its not there . Its an aspx page. For some reason unknown to me the $('.tableHeader').live( "click", function() { -Function seems to be able to access the element with class tableHeader while the other functions cannot.

Comment: In a documentation i read the following: Event handlers attached using the live() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements matching the selector (like a new element created by a script). 

Could this be the reason? Do I have to execute your scripts in another way? I thought $().ready(function () { is the was to go

Comment: Which documentation are you reading?  Here's the [live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) doc and it states:  *This API has been removed in jQuery 1.9; please use on() instead.*  v1.9 was released in 2013.  It was deprecated since v1.7 (2011).   **Edit** just noticed you're specifically using **1.5.2** - in which case, .live is ok - but regardless, that's for an event and you want it on load (or after your elements have loaded) - so is sort of irrelevant to the question as you're removing the event anyway.

Comment: I've only suggested replacing `.live(click)` with `.each` - ie keep the doc.ready.   If the elements aren't there when the page loads, then a doc.ready won't help you.  You'll need to wait/know when the elements are loaded; which you've not detailed in your question.  You *could* do a `setTimeout` but that's a very hit-and-miss (and a bit hacky) solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, very much appreciate it, setTimeout seems to work. I guess I try to write a periodic check if the element exists and then fire my code. Thanks again for your help!!